# Web Scraping Get Video From Blob

Tags: python, html, web

So I'm trying to get the video link from a the video found at
https://www.cnn.com/2018/04/25/cnn10/ten-content-thurs/index.html, specifically

`<video preload="metadata" webkit-playsinline="" width="100%" height="100%" src="blob:https://www.cnn.com/bfa3b957-ef83-4a88-8865-bcdfcedce7a5" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; pointer-events: none; position: absolute; left: 0px; right: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; z-index: 1;"></video>`

However, the src of the video is `blob:https://www.cnn.com/bfa3b957-ef83-4a88-8865-bcdfcedce7a5`, which after some research, could not find a clear answer on how to extract a video link out of the blob. I don't know if you can get the video url from a blob or not.

Comment: You can google around about _how to parse HTML with Python_ and you'll find a lot of useful information about this, including ways of extracting data from HTML documents.

Comment: I understand how to web srape, it's just getting a video link from the blob